# JQgrid - cannot get output from Json where value of array is Object, Object

Tags: json, jqgrid

I have 2 applications that use the free version of jqgrid.
The one that works has a Json array as follows;
[image]

Notice the value of data is [...]
For the application where the data does not get rendered;
[image] 
Notice the value of data is NOT [...]. So what do I need to do to the data to get it in the correct format so that it will render?

**EDIT**
I think the data issue I raised originally was mistaken.
I have a jsFiddle of what I want and it works, see 
https://jsfiddle.net/arame/cxh7zh3a/
But my code in my .Net MVC application does not. The grid is displayed with headers, but the data rows are not rendered.

```
var populateGrid = function (data) {
    var grid = $("#grid");
    grid.jqGrid({
        data: data,
        colNames: ["Contract No", "Title", ""],
        colModel: [
            { name: "FullContractNo", label: "FullContractNo", width: 80, align: "center" },
            { name: "ContractTitle", label: "ContractTitle", width: 400, searchoptions: { sopt: ["cn"] } },
            { name: "Link", label: "Link", search: false, align: "center" }
        ],
        cmTemplate: { width: 100, autoResizable: true },
        rowNum: 20,
        pager: "#pager",
        shrinkToFit: false,
        rownumbers: true,
        sortname: "FullContractNo",
        viewrecords: true
    });

    grid.jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
        beforeSearch: function () {
            return false; // allow filtering
        }
    }).jqGrid("gridResize");
    $("#divLoading").hide();
}

var getGrid = function () {
    var url = GetHiddenField("sir-get-selected-contract-list");
    var callback = populateGrid;
    dataService.getList(url, callback);
}

getGrid();
```

The code is a little different to the JsFiddle as the data is extracted from a Web API.
The data is correct however, as I put a breakpoint in and check it.
See 
[image]

Comment: Which version of [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) you use? You posted **not** the test array data, which can't be loaded by jqGrid. jqGrid can't read *any* array. The properties of input data should corresponds `name` property of the corresponding columns and the value should be read too. There are some additional possibilities, but I can't describe all the features in the comment. **It would be good if you post the demo** (in JSFiddle for example), which reproduces the problem. You can include 2-3 items or test data in the demo for every grid.

Comment: Can you post code both?

Comment: I have edited the question and put in your requests. As I mention, the jsFiddle actually works as I would like, see https://jsfiddle.net/arame/cxh7zh3a/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer! I feel daft posting this, but for some reason I cannot fathom I had an old version of the jqGrid library. I had version 4.7 and the current version is 4.14.
With the right version it is now working.